# Monoid and category

Tags: category-theory, monoid

Let $M$ be a monoid.
Let $a, b$ be elements of $M$.
We denote $\operatorname{Hom}(a, b) = \{s\ |\ sb = a\}$.
Then we get a category whose set of objects is $M$.
We denote this category by $C(M)$.
Let $M, N$ be monoids.
Suppose $C(M)$ is isomorphic to $C(N)$.
Is $M$ isomorphic to $N$?

Answer (score 7):

Your claim is false. Observe that, if $M$ is a group, then $C (M)$ is a category where there is exactly one morphism between any two objects. But the isomorphism class of such a category is determined uniquely by the cardinality of its object set. Thus, for example, $C (\mathbb{Z} / 4)$ is isomorphic to $C (\mathbb{Z} / 2 \times \mathbb{Z} / 2)$.